# set_time_limit is not affecting PHP-CLI

Tags: php

How to solve set_time_limit not affecting PHP-CLI?

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q 
<?php
set_time_limit(2);
sleep(5); // actually, exec() call that takes > 2 seconds
echo "it didn't work again";
```

Comment: As Pascal MARTIN points out, set_time_limit is not the correct approach. I need someway to kill this script after set seconds.

Comment: same problem, added bounty, need a way to stop the process cli process spawned by cron after 5 minutes

Comment: Just to clarify the bounty is not going to Pascal MARTIN, as his answer does not work for php-cli

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution here is to use `pcntl_fork()`. I'm afraid it's POSIX only. PHP will need to be compiled with `--enable-pcntl` and not `--disable-posix`. Your code should look something like this:

```
<?php

function done($signo)
{
    // You can do any on-success clean-up here.
    die('Success!');
}

$pid = pcntl_fork();
if (-1 == $pid) {
    die('Failed! Unable to fork.');
} elseif ($pid > 0) {
    pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, 'done');
    sleep($timeout);
    posix_kill($pid, SIGKILL);
    // You can do any on-failure clean-up here.
    die('Failed! Process timed out and was killed.');
} else {
    // You can perform whatever time-limited operation you want here.
    exec($cmd);
    posix_kill(posix_getppid(), SIGALRM);
}

?>
```

Basically what this does is fork a new process which runs the `else { ... }` block. At the (successful) conclusion of that we send an alarm back to the parent process, which is running the `elseif ($pid > 0) { ... }` block. That block has a registered signal handler for the alarm signal (the `done()` callback) which terminates successfully. Until that is received, the parent process sleeps. When the timeout `sleep()` is complete, it sends a `SIGKILL` to the (presumably hung) child process.

Answer (score 19):

The [**`max_execution_time`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) limit, which is what  [**`set_time_limit`**](http://fr.php.net/set_time_limit) sets, counts *(at least, on Linux)* the time that is spent by the PHP process, while working.

Quoting the manual's page of `set_time_limit()` :

> **Note:** The `set_time_limit()` function and the configuration
>   directive `max_execution_time`  **only
>   affect the execution time of the
>   script itself**. 
> Any time spent on
>   activity that happens outside the
>   execution of the script such as system
>   calls using `system()`, stream
>   operations, database queries, etc. is
>   not included when determining the
>   maximum time that the script has been
>   running. 
> This is not true on
>   Windows where the measured time is
>   real.

When, you are using `sleep()`, your PHP script is not working : it's just waiting... So the 5 seconds you are waiting are not being taken into account by the `max_execution_time` limit.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however i still have the solve the problem, is there anyway that I can do this using another approach ?

Comment: Well, I'd say should not not `sleep()`, if you don't want the script to remain alive for more time than necessaray ;-) ;;; more seriously, `max_execution_time` is meant as a security precaution against scripts that would take too much resources, and not as any kind of precise timing mecanism.

Comment: there is an exec() running instead of sleep() there. and some exec() stuff hangs indefinitely. i am also searching for killing it from within exec (on linux shell), like exec(kill_after15secs myscript.sh), but i can't seem to find that either...

Comment: Oh, I understand better, now, why you need this ^^ ;;; sorry, I don't have any realy solution, there :-(

Answer (score 6):

Could you try running your php via exec and use the "timeout" command? (http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/timeout)

usage: timeout [-signal] time command.

Comment: Super simple, works just as expected e.g. `timeout 5m /usr/bin/php /var/www/example.com/cron.php`

Answer (score 5):

Very hackish, but since I use cli scripts a lot, I admit *shamefully* to having slapped up a similar hack in the past. 2 scripts needed.

Your first cron script (the one that hangs)  logs its starttime and processid in a  flat file -> the function getmypid will be your friend for this. A second script run from cron every (x) minutes checks the flatfile, kills whatever has passed the alloted execution time, clears the flatfile and even logs in another file if you want.

Good luck ;)

**UPDATE:**

Remembered this question and came back to post this. While rummaging through Sebastian Bergmann's github account I stumbled on [php-invoker](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-invoker). In the words of the author:

> > Utility class for invoking PHP callables with a timeout.

Although the current answer is very good for linux based non portable use, if cross-platform solution is needed this solution should be windows compatible, for those poor souls running on windoze. Mr Bergmann being a PHP god, I totally vouch for the quality of the script.

Comment: you would need some sort of cron jobs manager to handle starting/logging/stopping processes automatically, but it would work nicely

Answer (score 4):

I'm ssuming that the script hangs in a loop somewhoere. Why not simply do a `$STARTUP_TIME=time()` the the script start, and then keep checking in the loop if the script neeeds to exit?

Comment: +1 it's only normal way. I don't understand, why it wasn't used and wasn't suggested early.

Comment: @OZ: If the script *exec* utes a process it'll block -- wait for the child process to terminate -- before moving on to the next instruction in the script. If the executed process returns control to the script immediately (e.g. by using the bash's `&` operator), this logic will work.

Answer (score 2):

## EDIT 1

I noticed this comment in PHP manual:

> Please note that, under Linux,
>   sleeping time is ignored, but under
>   Windows, it counts as execution time.

As far as what I understand, sleep is implemented as a system call and therefore ignored by PHP [as described in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

## EDIT 2

> there is an exec() running instead of
>   sleep() there. and some exec() stuff
>   hangs indefinitely. i am also
>   searching for killing it from within
>   exec (on linux shell), like
>   exec(kill_after15secs myscript.sh),
>   but i can't seem to find that either

I now see the actual question. Assuming that you're working in a Lunix/Unix environment, you can devise a solution around these lines:

```
<?php $pid = system( 'sh test.sh >test-out.txt 2>&1 & echo $!' ); ?>
```

Guess what, this captured the process id of the process you started. You can log it into a database or text file along with timestamp. In another cron script that runs, say, every 5 minutes, retrieve all process ids that were created 5 minutes ago and check if they are still running:

```
<?php $status = system( 'ps ' . $pid ); ?>
```

If process is still running, you get two lines of output:

```
 PID TTY STAT TIME COMMAND
2044 ?   S    0:29 sh test.sh
```

If so, terminate it like this:

```
<?php system( 'kill ' . $pid ); ?>
```

I wrote an article about [creating background processes in PHP](https://salman-w.blogspot.com/2010/04/running-background-process-in-php.html) (and hunt them down afterwards). All examples were copied from there.

## EDIT 3

All dots connected together:

```
<?php
    $pid = system( 'sh test.sh >test-out.txt 2>&1 & echo $!' );
    $timer = 300;
    while( --$timer ) {
        sleep(1);
        $status = system( 'ps ' . $pid );
        $status = explode( "\n", $status, 2 ); // I am not sure, please experiment a bit here
        if ( count( $status ) == 1 || trim( $status[ 1 ] ) == '' ) {
            die( 'spawned process ended successfully' );
        }
    }
    system( 'kill ' . $pid );
    die( 'spawned process was terminated' );
?>
```